# Python tkinter - ttk - bind - Replace pressed character with another one

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-entry

I want to write in a TTK entry a specific character when a key is pressed, removing from the entry the character related to that specific key.

For example:

If I press * I want that in the entry is entered × and not ×* like how I tried to do this (see below)

At the moment I did this but it's not working as expected (in this extract there aren't the imports and Window is not defined):

```
def writeToEntry(text, delete=False):
    if delete:
        e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(END, text)
    e.focus_set()

e = Entry(w)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew")
e.bind('*', lambda event: writeToEntry("×"))
e.bind('/', lambda event: writeToEntry("÷"))
```

Could you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Read about [The Variable Classes - `.trace`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to return the string "break" to prevent the original character from being inserted.

```
def writeToEntry(text, delete=False):
    if delete:
        e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(END, text)
    e.focus_set()
    return "break"
```